# Running a task for days - Android

Tags: android, service, android-location

I' m developing an Android App that will log the user's GPS location onto a .txt file saved on the cellphone. I' m thinking about a 5-10 minute interval and it should run throughout the day. The GPS location should also be logged even if the App itself is not in the foreground or when the cellphones goes on stand-by.

Was wondering what class should I look into? Service? AlarmManagers? Will a service continue to run even when the app is not in the foreground or when the phone goes to stand-by?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ofcourse Service...STICKY Service I mean:)

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [TimerTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) and [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html).

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timer_task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // GPS related method
    }
};
timer.schedule(timer_task, delay, period);
```

> delay  = long: amount of time in milliseconds before first execution.
>
> period = long: amount of time in milliseconds between subsequent
>   executions

.